# does VPS rely on SSD?

Tags: ssd, performance, vps

I have recently starting using a Linode and a Digital Ocean droplet. I have not had speed problems with either one, and that led me to wonder exactly how they balance resources among the various VPSs on a given physical machine.

For CPU it seems straightforward: a VPS gets to use one (or more?) of the CPUs for some number of milliseconds, then control transfers to another VPS.

For disk, it also seems straightforward with a solid-state drive.

But if the drive was a hard disk, it seems much more difficult to keep one VPS's disk use from interfering with that of other VPSs'.

So my question is simply: did the advent of cheap solid-state drives fundamentally make VPSs more compartmentalized and reliable?

Comment: A VPS does not require the use of SSD, when SSDs were more expensive (i.e. $5 per GB), you would typically pay extra so your VPS would be stored on an SSD instead of a mechanical drive.  VPS are compartmentalized due to the hypervisor not due to what storage device they use.

Comment: Right, my question is: When SSD cost was prohibitive and VPS used hard disk, was it harder to keep a VPS from causing performance issues for other VPSs on the same machine?

Comment: Yes - HDD performance was/is a major concern when provisioning general purpose VPS's.